# Как перенести значение переменной из одного хендлера в другой. Используя FSM

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Всем привет, у меня такая делема, я не могу понять как перенести значение переменной из одного хендлера в другой. Я для этого пытаюсь использовать FSM, вот пример кода.

```
    @dp.message_handler(state=FMS.waite_user_id)
    async def pvp_reg_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        user_id_player_1 = message.from_user.id  # Кто отправляет
        await state.update_data(user_id_player_2=message.text)#противник
        await state.update_data(user_id_player_1=user_id_player_1)# Кто отправляет
        user_id_players = await state.get_data() #Кому отправляет
        await state.reset_state(with_data=False)
        print(user_id_players['user_id_player_1'])
```

Вот тут я пытаюсь получить `await state.update_data(user_id_player_1=user_id_player_1)# Кто отправляет`

```
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text="Acc", state="*")
    async def Accept_Pvp(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
        user_id_players = await state.get_data()
        player_1 = user_id_players.get("user_id_player_2")
        print(player_1)
        await call.answer()
        await state.finish()
```

На выходе мне выдает None

Comment: Через третью сущность - базу данных, очередь или стек... Любую независимую от обоих хэндлеров сущность.

Comment: Проверил твой код у себя, у меня всё работает.  https://pastebin.com/phBtRBGF  Может ты где-то сбрасываешь стейт или перезаписываешь данные?